# why $\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta=\cos(\beta - \alpha)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors

I'm studying linear algebra and there is a chapter in a book that says about unit vector and it says this $$ \cos\alpha \cos\beta + \sin\alpha \sin\beta = \cos(\beta - \alpha) $$ Why?? I'm newbie and need very detail answer. Does the alpha and beta just represent angle a and angle b and has no special meaning???

you can have a look at the attached picture from the book:

[image: content from the book]

Answer (score 4):

Let $u = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta )$, and $v = (\cos \beta, \sin \beta)$, then $u\cdot v = ||u||\cdot ||v||\cdot \cos (\beta - \theta)$, and from this your identity follows.

Comment: if u⋅v then why don't we get cosαcosβ+sinαsinβ ? why you write u⋅v=||u||⋅||v||⋅cos(β−θ) ? I don't understand, can you please explain more detail?

Comment: The angle formed when you rotate from $u$ to $v$ is precisely $\beta - \theta$, and its also the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the (counter-clockwise) rotation matrix by angle $\theta$ is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Consider rotating ccw by an angle of $\beta$ and then clockwise by an angle of $\alpha$.  This corresponds to the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\beta-\alpha)&-\sin(\beta-\alpha)\\\sin(\beta-\alpha)&\cos(\beta-\alpha)\end{bmatrix}.
$$

On the other hand, this can be computed by applying the rotations one at a time and multiplying the matrices.  In other words, this rotation is the same as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(-\alpha)&-\sin(-\alpha)\\\sin(-\alpha)&\cos(-\alpha)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\beta)&-\sin(\beta)\\\sin(\beta)&\cos(\beta)\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\alpha)&\sin(\alpha)\\-\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\beta)&-\sin(\beta)\\\sin(\beta)&\cos(\beta)\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since these are two different ways of writing the same thing, the corresponding entries are the same, and hence $\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)=\cos(\beta-\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some of the above answers use the property more so than prove it or state where it comes from. For a basic geometric proof, see http://www.themathpage.com/atrig/sum-proof.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, the essential content of your answer should be posted here.